# How to call the number of list item inside for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am writing a for loop that is fetching Google Trends from the pytrends package. Now I want the for loop to create a dataframe for every keyword it is finding in the list of keywords. But I want the dataframes to be named after the number of the list item instead of the actual string in the list.

Right now this is my code:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq(hl='de', tz=390, retries=10, backoff_factor=0.5)

keywords = ['foo', 'bar', 'dummy']

for keyword in keywords:
  try:
    pytrend.build_payload(
      kw_list=[keyword],
      geo='DE',
      timeframe = 'now 1-d')
    gbl = globals()
    gbl['df_'+[str(i) for i in range(len(keywords))]] = pytrend.interest_over_time()
    gbl['df_'+[str(i) for i in range(len(keywords))]] = gbl['df_'+[str(i) for i in range(len(keywords))]].drop(labels=['isPartial'],axis='columns')
    print(keyword + ' was succesfully pulled from Google Trends')
  except Exception as e:
    print(keyword + ' was not successfully pulled because of the following error: ' + str(e))
    continue
```

But unfortunately this gives me the following errors:

```
foo was not successfully pulled because of the following error: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
bar was not successfully pulled because of the following error: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
dummy was not successfully pulled because of the following error: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

So, my question is, how do I grab the number of the item in the list to create `df_0`, `df_1`, `df_2`, etc.?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with adding string to list.

You probably wanted a loop to be a bit more outside and also you may use *enumarete* which will give you a loop having both item and its number

```
for i, keyword in enumerate(keywords):
  gbl['df_'+str(i)] = ... something using keyword ...
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do that, thank you so much. It works like a charm!

Comment: Also, would you be able to help on how to then add these three dataframe objects to a list in the same loop? I would like to eventually do: `df_final = pd.concat([dfs], axis=1, join='outer', sort=True)`

Comment: Create empty list outside the loop. Then call append. If I understan your plan corecly.

Comment: I have added the empty list on top and `df_list.append(gbl['df_'+str(i)])` and outside the loop `df_de = pd.concat([[df_list]], axis=1, join='outer', sort=True)` to the code, but that returns a print of the dfs inside a loop instead of the dataframe objects, judging from this final error: `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Answer (score 1):

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq(hl='de', tz=390, retries=10, backoff_factor=0.5)

keywords = ['foo', 'bar', 'dummy']

for keyword in keywords:
  try:
    pytrend.build_payload(
      kw_list=[keyword],
      geo='DE',
      timeframe = 'now 1-d')
    gbl = globals()
    for i in range(len(keywords)):
        gbl['df_'+str(i)] = pytrend.interest_over_time()
        gbl['df_'+str(i)] = gbl['df_'+str(i)].drop(labels=['isPartial'],axis='columns')
    print(keyword + ' was successfully pulled from Google Trends')
  except Exception as e:
    print(keyword + ' was not successfully pulled because of the following error: ' + str(e))
    continue
```

I made certain changes to your code and it worked.

This is the output.

```
foo was successfully pulled from Google Trends
bar was successfully pulled from Google Trends 
dummy was successfully pulled from Google Trends
```

The problem with the above code is that you cannot append a list to string.

```
gbl['df_'+[str(i) for i in range(len(keywords))]] = pytrend.interest_over_time()
gbl['df_'+[str(i) for i in range(len(keywords))]] = gbl['df_'+[str(i) for i in range(len(keywords))]]
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the data in the df only comes from the last payload in the loop before the for i in range(len(keywords)): loop if I see it correctly.

Comment: yes, you are correct. only the last payload will be stored. But if you want to store all the payloads for all the keywords then using a 2-D list would serve the purpose.
for ex : i  -> payload no , j -> keyword w.r.t that payload